# aws ec2 : Instance unreachable before schedule

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I've received email from aws stating that one of my ec2 instance is scheduled for retirement due to underlying hardware degradation on 1st September 2017. When I checked that instance after receiving the email, It was already unreachable and `0/2 health check passed`. I did couple of reboot from aws web console after which instance got up and running with status `2/2 health check passed` Now my question is Will it still be unreachable after 1st September 2017? I am having basic support plan and hence can't raise this with aws directly. I highly appreciate community support here.

Note: It's a EBS backed ubuntu linux instance. If you find this question meaningful kindly upvote.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Will it still be unreachable after 1st September 2017"

You need to STOP and then START then instance to move it to new hardware. If you did a REBOOT then it will stop working on 1st September. A simple stop / start cycle will mean it will stay available.

You can read up on instance lifecycles [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-lifecycle.html). It doesn't explicitly say about the hardware, I learned that during certification study. It's probably in the documentation somewhere, but there's so much documentation for AWS it can be difficult to locate.

Comment: There's not a separate thing called "restart."  There is only "reboot" and "stop/start."  "Restart" is sometimes used in the documentation for "stop/start."  If an instance scheduled for retirement came back to life after being in the 0/2 health check passed state, then almost certainly either a stop/start was already performed (not a reboot -- a reboot can't happen in the 0/2 state -- you can't reboot a system with an inaccessible hypervisor, and that's what the first check is testing).  That, or the hypervisor is flaky and recovered coincident with (not because of) the reboot attempt.

Comment: There is an explicit reference to the hardware.  [*"When you stop a running instance... in most cases, the instance is migrated to a new underlying host computer when it's started."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Stop_Start.html) The "most cases" caveat presumably would apply in a constrained capacity environment where there isn't any other hardware available, or to placement groups in some cases, or dedicated hosts... but a VM should never start up on a physical machine already flagged as degraded, so the caveat almost certainly never applies, here.

Comment: Yep you're right Michael, I said "restart" when I meant "reboot". I think of them as generally the same, so I tend to use the words interchangeably. I did clearly say stop then start is what needs to happen here.

Answer (score 1):

According to AWS Docs:

> An instance is scheduled to be retired when AWS detects irreparable
>   failure of the underlying hardware hosting the instance. Your instance
>   root device is an Amazon EBS volume so the instance will be stopped,
>   and you can start it again at any time.

You have two options here:

1. Wait for the scheduled retirement date, when the instance is stopped you can start it again at any time or
2. Create an EBS-backed AMI from your instance, and launch a replacement instance. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-ebs.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, doesn't cover all the options, and your point #2 is only correct if the instance is based on ephemeral disk.

Comment: You're wrong. Look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html)

Comment: *"An instance is scheduled to be retired when AWS detects irreparable failure of the underlying hardware hosting the instance."*  This sentence is copy/pasted from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-retirement.html) and presented here as if they are your own words --
 without proper attribution.  Please review the help section [**"How to reference material written by others."**](https://serverfault.com/help/referencing)

Comment: Point #2 is technically possible for EBS-backed instances, but is unnecessary unless for some reason your degraded instance is an EBS-backed spot instance, in which case you can actually make an AMI from it after it fails, and often end up with a usable image. (EBS-backed spot instances, like instance-store, cannot be stopped, they can only be terminated.) Overlooked in this answer: stop/start **now** to move away from the degraded hardware and automatically clear the scheduled retirement event for the instance.

Comment: Though I'm certainly not always right, I don't believe I'm wrong here. #1 misses the main thing you need to do, which is stop and start the instance. #2 is largely unnecessary as you can use the EBS volume without creating an AMI.

Comment: But the OP has mentioned it is EBS backed instance

Comment: Yes, it's EBS backed. That means when the instance stops at the scheduled time the compute is no longer available, but the EBS volume is still available. Therefore you can just start a new EC2 instance using the existing EBS volume.